# Is it possible to prevent the "Change execution policy" dialog after the first start of my script?

Tags: powershell

I'm using Windows 10 and have a custom powershell script that lets me create a PDF from .tex files and images via PDFLatex. Also, folders are copied, renamed and compressed into a .zip. When I start my script on another PC, the dialog "Change execution policy" is displayed when I run it for the 1st time . And I don't want to change the policy.:

"Change execution policy The execution policy helps protect against untrusted scripts. change, If you are using the Execution Policy, you may need to refer to the "about_Execution_Policies" help topic at https: /go. Microsoft. com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170". Do you want to change the execution policy? []] Yes [A] Yes, all [N] No [K] No, none [H] Stop [?] Help (Default is "N"):"

If I choose No, the window closes. If I start the script again afterwards, it is executed without displaying the dialog again. What could be the reason for this? Is it possible to prevent this dialog on the 1st call?

In my script I use commands like:

```
Write-Host
# Change zip Backslash to Forward to be compatible with Unix, use I.O.Compression to zip files
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'
[System.AppContext]::SetSwitch('Switch.System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.UseBackslash', $false)
Get-ChildItem
Copy-Item
Read-Host
Rename-Item
$string.Replace
Remove-Item
ROBOCOPY
```

Is it possible that one of the commands triggers the dialog?

Thank you and best regards
Ramona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no way to get rid of the message without changing the execution policy.
The options I see are

1. Sign your script
   This needs an valid CA either a local one, deployed by your organization, or a global one like DigiCert or similar. Note that global singing is not free.
2. Run your script as Administrator. This might be a security risk but an admin instance should not ask for changing the execution policy.
3. Instead of running the script in a "regular" PowerShell window your could open the script in the [ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3). The ISE has a more permissive execution policy than the regular PowerShell console, so your script should run without any prompts.
4. (not really an option since this changes the execution policy)
   Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` before the script, then run the script, then run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted` to re-enable the restricted policy.

Comment: Number 3 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that your script contains a [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) call that tries to change the script [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) or that it calls another script or command from a module that makes such a call, but that call doesn't include the `-Force` switch, so *interactive confirmation* is required in order to change the policy.

The fact that the dialog no longer appears even when you *decline* the confirmation prompt implies - assuming that you haven't run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` yourself in the meantime - that the script maintains a persistent setting somewhere to implement one-time-per-machine logic for the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call, so that it remembers whether it has made the call before - seemingly irrespective of whether it succeeded or not - and doesn't call again.

You have two options:

- If you can modify the script or module that ultimately makes this call, simply *remove* the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call (it arguably should never have been included in a script whose purpose is unrelated to execution policies).

  - You can make the following [`Set-PSBreakpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint) call *before running your script*, which will help you isolate where, specifically, the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call is made:

    ```bash
    Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy
    ```
- Otherwise - and this may not be feasible - find out what the persistence mechanism is that the script uses to remember whether the call has been made (e.g. a configuration file, registry key, or persistent environment variable) and *programmatically* set it so that the script thinks it has already called - which you'll have to do on/for every machine (possibly remotely), *before* first invocation.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser. But in my script I never try to `Set-ExecutionPolicy`. This is why I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: @RamonaK.,then it must be code that is called _from_ your script, such as a another script file or a command from a module. PowerShell would never by itself make such a call.

Comment: I tried to start a script with only tow lines in it: `$log = ".\log\gen_ps1.log" 
ECHO "Generating..." ` and there is the same. When I start the script the first time, the dialog appears. I also added the breakpoint, the result is: ` ID Script                      Line Command                     Variable                   Action
  -- ------                      ---- -------                     --------                   ------
   0                                  Set-ExecutionPolicy`

Comment: Sorry for the bad format -.-

Comment: @RamonaK, you're quoting the output from the `Set-PSBreakpoint` call itself, which you can ignore. What I suggested was: On a machine where you haven't yet run the script before, make the `Set-PSBreakpoint` call interactively, then run the script for the first time. Script execution should then pause when the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is made, revealing the source -file path, line number, and relevant source-code line. Are you saying you did that, and the script didn't pause?

Comment: Oh, I put the breakpoint at the begging of the script -.- Do I have to call the breakpoint and to start the script in the same terminal?

Comment: @RamonaK, putting at the start of the script should work too (I thought it would be easier not to modify the script.) So the breakpoint is never hit?

Comment: When I call it from the script, at the first run the dialog still appears. After second run I get the output from above.

Comment: @RamonaK., the output you're seeing isn't the breakpoint being _hit_, it is the output from the `Set-PSBreakpoint` call itself (describing the newly created breakpoint). If you didn't see this output until _after_ the execution-policy prompt and you really placed the `Set-PSBreakpoint` _at the very start_ of your script, the implication is that something _outside_ the script triggers the prompt - possibly even something outside of PowerShell - but I wouldn't know where to look. Do you know your organization's policies around PowerShell execution policies?

Comment: @mlement0 when I call `Get EcecutionPolicy` I get `RemoteSigned`. Is this what you mean?